# QT mainwidget and connected widget(parent=NULL)

Tags: qt5, overlay

Environement: Qt5.8 c++ Windows/MacOs

Hello,
i have the situation, taht i want to show a non parented widget over my main app (here a video is playing), this works fine generally but, the problem is, when i switch over to another app (or use alt-tab) the non parented widget (flag staysalways on top) shows then up over the foreign app.

the non parented widget is created in my mainapp in the way

```
QWidget *overlay = new QWidget(NULL);
```

so perhaps somebody has had already this problem and can help me here a little bit

with regards 
Georg